# Smooth scroll in IOS 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, smooth-scrolling

I am implementing smooth scrolling in my div, and inside the same div I am using the jquery drag. While I am dragging the inner div the outer div on which I am using smooth scroll is going blank. Do any body have idea why is this happening. I will be very thankful if anybody can come up with any sort of solution.

Comment: I would disable it for mobile phones, it is already smooth for them.

Comment: no on disabling that thing the scroll is becoming resistive. Do you have any other alternative for smooth scroll.